# Adding multiple values to the same column in Python Sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, flask

I have created a table to store information and data for each user in a simple social media website. I have the column "friends" and I want this column to have multiple values seperated by a comma. for example, "John, Maria, Batman etc...". Shortly, each time the user clicks at the Follow Button, the name of the another person is being added to the column "friends".

```
with sqlite3.connect('memory.db') as conn:
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute(
         "CREATE TABLE users (user_id char(50), name char(50), email char(50), password char(30), "
         "university char(50), birthday char(50), age char(10), hometown char(50), photo, status char(50), friends char(1000));")

     name = session['name']  #the name of the user
     name_search = session['name_search']  #the name of the person who we want to follow
     if name != name_search:  
         cursor.execute('''UPDATE users SET friends=? WHERE name=?''', (name_search, name))
         conn.commit()
```

I've used the method UPDATE but it updates the column only with the one value...

Comment: That's poor DB design. Very basic example - you should have one table `users` and one table `friends`. in table `freinds` there should be one friend per row and user_id being the foreign key that links to respective user in `users` table. There will be one-to-many relation between `users` and `friends`.

Comment: If you are planning to store the friends of each user in the column `friends` as a comma separated list, don't do it.